# File can't be attached to a cloned html input element

Tags: jquery, cakephp

**Cakephp**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('images.', array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'class' => 'span12 tolet_img',
        'style' => 'width:100%;',
        'div' => array('class' => 'span8 required')
        )
    );
?>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var uploaderCount = 0;
    var $htmlString = $('.uploader:last').clone(true);
    $('.tolet_img').click(function(){    
        $htmlString.attr('id', 'uniform-file-'+uploaderCount);
        $htmlString.find('input[type=file]').attr('id', 'file-'+uploaderCount);
        uploaderCount++;
        $('.uploader:last').after($htmlString);
    });
});
```

New input field is created by this code I inspect code. All are okay. But Element created by jquery does not attached file. To explain my problem I attached the screenshot:
[image]

2nd input field is created successfully after first input field is clicked but when 2nd input field is clicked and trying to attach another file it does not attach and remains empty.
 Here is the live Demo:
 http://www.jegeachi.com/tolets/add

Whats wrong am I doing. It kills my two days. It approximately make me cry. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var uploaderCount = 0;
var $htmlString = $('.uploader:last').clone(true);

$(document).on("click",".tolet_img" function() {  
     $htmlString.attr('id', 'uniform-file-'+uploaderCount);
     $htmlString.find('input[type=file]').attr('id', 'file-'+uploaderCount);
        uploaderCount++;
     $('.uploader:last').after($htmlString);
});
```

The toilet_img element is not in the same scope when you re-create it.